# CSS Formatting for input fields

Tags: html, css, format

hello i am new to html and want to be able to position my fields and text the way i describe it in the photo below, here is my html part,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiw8o.jpg

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  /* This sets the background for all the pages*/
  background-image: url('static/shard.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* 'no-repeat' makes the background not 
        repeat on the web page */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('sign') }}" method="post">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
  <label for="comments">Comments</label>
  <input type="text" name="Comments" id="comments">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign">
</form>
```

Comment: Well first things first, the font tag is no longer used, what you want to have is a label.

In the other hand, you need to check the basics of CSS (I can recommend you to check codecademy) since what you are asking is some really basic styling and for what I see you haven't tried just yet.

Comment: I  think you should start playing with the CSS `grid` property.  It's way simpler to use plus the whole purpose is to allow us to create our own layout and just apply a `grid-area` property to the elements we want to display in a designated space.  It makes it so we don't have to be grand wizards just to get a `<div>` to show up in the same place in 3 different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

For a layout as simple as that, I would do the next:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('sign') }}" method="post">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" name="Email" id="email">
  <label for="comments">Comments</label>
  <input type="text" name="Comments" id="comments">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign">
</form>
<style>
  form {
    display:  flex; 
    flex-direction:  column; 
    align-items:  center; 
    justify-content:  center; 
  }
</style>
```

That's only for the layout. Check this reference for layouting purposes: [Flexbox Layouts](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Be careful to not use `<font>` tags, as they are now deprecated in HTML5

Comment: thanks! this helps a bit as it now puts everything in the top center of the page, how can i put the text above the input field in the center? also how can i increase the size of say the comment input field

Comment: For centering again you can review the guide on Flexbox Layouts. It depends on what you want to achieve. In this case you can put the form inside a wrapper with the same `display: flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; justify-content: center; width: 100vw; height: 100vh;` CSS. 

For this kind of things there are lots of resources out there such as W3Schools, CSSTricks, CodePen, etcetera to get started. :)

Comment: Also, do some research on the `margin` and `padding` CSS properties. At first code can be a little overwhelming, but you can do it.